# Verilog implementation of "Majority" function

Tags: function, verilog, xilinx

I guess I don't know enough about this Majority function to wrap my head around it... I just don't know where to begin with this. I'm no pro Verilog yet lol

[image]

It's defined as a function of x, y, and z, so I'm thinking the function would be a function of three binary input bits. Beyond that I'm lost.

Any help/direction appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In boolean terms, a majority gate is true if more than half it's inputs are true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function

If you think about it those simple terms than the 3 input example is fairly simple. There are only 3 situations that will result in a true.

(X AND Y) OR (Y AND Z) OR (X AND Z)

You may want to extend that to an arbitrary number of inputs and that is what the equation is for. My verilog is fairly rusty so I don't remember right off but I think that you can do that kind of math with binary inputs if you so choose.